# .htaccess file creates 403 error on my Hostgator website

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I’m having a problem with my .htaccess file on my hostgator site.  My URL is traversymvc.thinkcomutationally.org.
I’m trying to make pretty URLs as done in the tutorial I’m following but when I use the .htaccess file below.  I get a 403 error if I Use the URL traversymvc.thinkcomputationally.org/public,  it works.  But I should not have to use the public directory name.  I want to be able to type traversymvc.thinkcomputationally.org/pages and go to the correct page on my website.
Code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /traversymvc.thinkcomutationally.org
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `traversymvc.thinkcomutationally.org` looks like a hostname, not part of the URL-path? Where is the `index.php` file located? You mention a `/public` subdirectory? Is that where all the files are stored? Where is the `.htaccess` file located? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteBase /traversymvc.thinkcomutationally.org
> ```

Unless `index.php` is located in a `/traversymvc.thinkcomutationally.org` subdirectory then you should remove the `RewriteBase` directive or possibly set this to `RewriteBase /public` if `index.php` is located in the `/public` subdirectory (which could be implied by your example).

The presence of the `RewriteBase` directive as written would result in the request being internally rewritten to `https://example.com/traversymvc.thinkcomutationally.org/index.php` - where `example.com` is the requested hostname/domain and `/traversymvc.thinkcomutationally.org` is a physical subdirectory.

The `RewriteBase` directive sets the URL-path that is added back to relative *substitution* strings. (`index.php?url=$1` is a relative substiution string.) You don't need this at all (and should not use it) if `index.php` is in the same directory that contains the `.htaccess` file. (In fact, even if its not in the same directory you still don't *need* it, as you can include the correct path directly in the subst string.)

Comment: Thank you so much for responding.  traversymvc is my subdomain in my hostgator account thinkcomputationally.com

Comment: @Diggee17 Did this answer your question / help resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hostgator gave me a new .htaccess file to use in my subdomain that worked.   I would have never figured it out.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php81” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php81___lsphp .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```